# How to check null response in .pipe(map) Rxjs operators?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```js
getDetailsById(eId: number): Observable<Details> {
  return this.api.post('detailsapi', cacheOptions, { Id: eId })
    .pipe(
      map((eDetails: any) => ({
        id: eDetails.eId,
        subDetails: this.mapSubDetails(eDetails.eSubDetails || [])
      })),
      catchError((err) => {
        const template: Template = {   
          id: 0,
          subEquipment: []
        };
        return Observable.throw(err)
      })
    );
}
```

I'd like to check in above code if `eDetails` is null or not. If null then I want to stop all the calls in  `Observable.forkJoin`.

Comment: which `Observable.forkJoin`?

Comment: Where's the `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a `filter` in the `pipe`:

```
.pipe(filter(isNotNull))
```

And use a typeguard for the same:

```
export function isNotNull<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421833/8205497
which does the same as the answer from nircraft

```
    // add this import on top of your source file
    import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'

    this.getFoo(fooId)
        .pipe(filter(x) => !!x)
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: The syntax here is broken (Closing parenthesis of filter should be after !xx, not x).

Comment: Additionally, nircraft's answer has added functionality. By making it a function, it can define the return value as "is NonNullable<T>". Your example doesn't account for that, so if the type of the pipe was "Observable<T | undefined>", it'd stay like that after the filter too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative - if defining a function per nircraft's answer is not ideal:
`.pipe(filter(x => x != null))` (or even `.pipe(filter(x => !!x))`)

But this will not have the correct type information by itself.
If the original observable was nullable, like:
`const subject = new Subject<boolean | undefined>();`
Then you'd expect this to return `Observable<boolean>`:
`subject.pipe(filter(x => x != null))`

But instead, it stays Observable<boolean | undefined>.
However, you can fix this with a simple map:
`.pipe(filter(x => x != null), map(x => x!))`